# put link into href using javascript variable html

Tags: javascript, html

I have this:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
    
    //put the url of the girl into the quotes of imgUrl
    var imgUrl = "https://www.linkpicture.com/q/IMG_4902."
    
    //put the name of the model into the quotes of modelName
    var modelName = "modelName"
    
    //put the link to their instagram into the quotes of instagram
    var instagram = "https://www.instagram.com/gianluca/"
    
    
    document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = modelName;
    document.getElementById("myImg").src = imgUrl;
    document.getElementById("instagram").innerHTML = instagram;
    }
    </script>
<body onload="myFunction()">
            <img src="" id="myImg" alt="">
            <h2 id="myText"></h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="" id="instagram"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
```

I am trying to use the variable `instagram`, and put it into the `href`, but I cannot figure out how to do it. How is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to put the Instagram variable into href?

Comment: @YohanMalshika yes, exactly. So I can click the element and it'll take me to instagram.

Comment: Did you try this one,  document.getElementById("instagram").href = Instagram;   ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to the end of your code in the script

```
document.getElementById("instagram").href = instagram
```